# String.Contains() : Multiple character - C#

Tags: c#, string

I have this piece of code:

```
description="EUR CMS Swap";
description_token=description.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
bool check;

if(description_token.Contains("EUR CMS"))
   check=true;
```

But `check` is always false, even though

```
description_token[0]="EUR"  
description_token[1]="CMS"
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source value you have gets split into the array by spaces, so you should have `three` objects in your array

(EUR, CMS and Swap)

So you should rewrite your check to be

```
if(description_token.Contains("EUR") || description_token.Contains("CMS"))
```

(if it is enough if just one of the values is inside that array)

or

```
if(description_token.Contains("EUR") && description_token.Contains("CMS"))
```

(if both values HAVE to be inside that array)

Answer (score 3):

You either have to look for substrings or you have to compare all items:

1. substring:

   ```
   bool check = description.Contains("EUR CMS");
   ```
2. LINQ with `Enumerable.All`:

   ```
   string[] tokens = "EUR CMS".Split();
   bool check = tokens.All(t => description_token.Contains(t));
   ```
3. LINQ with `Enumerable.Any` (at least one match)

   ```
   bool check = tokens.Any(t => description_token.Contains(t));
   ```

The first approach checks if the given string is a substring of a larger, the second approach checks if all tokens are contained in the larger collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Contains` in that way. No single element contains "EUR CMS" after it's been split. You can either perform the check prior to splitting the string (using `description.Contains("EUR CMS"`) or after the split by checking for EUR and CMS separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(description_token.Contains("EUR") && description_token.Contains("CMS"))
 check=true;
```